# TinyMCE Custom Dropdown Set Text

Tags: jquery, editor, tinymce

I added custom select dropdown box in TinyMCE and want to add text on selectiong upon that list item in cursor position in tinymce box.

How can I set that text in tinyMCE on that cursor point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to issue this code on dropdown selection

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'my_text');
```